# What API to choose for data serialization to xml?

Tags: java

I need to save user data between sessions. So I decided to using binary serialization and start saving data in xml. After some research I found several APIs, namely JAXB and xStream.

I looked through samples of xStream and I like it. It is very simple. In two words: you give an object and receive .xml representation of this object. Read an xml and receive object back.

Then I read about JAXB - it is very strong, functional. But all examples I found are about creating of xml schema, generating java classes basing on this schema and so on. At the moment  it looks a little bit time consuming for me to describe my classes in .xsd. I hope it is one of many sides of JAXB usage. But what I saw, feared me a little.

Are there any other APIs that suit my task. Or what are pros and cons of JAXB and xStream then?

Comment: have a look at http://jibx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The subject is quite extensively covered already:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867353/what-is-the-simplest-and-minimalistic-java-xml-api?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736343/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-java-object-to-xml-with-open-source-apis?rq=1

Still, I gave you my answer below. :)

Comment: You may find the following useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with `JAXB` as it is built-in and easy to use. You do not need to start with an `XSD`. Just add some annotations to your classes.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="doc")
public class Document {
   @XmlElement
   protected Foo foo;
   // ...
}
```

Serialization:

```
Document doc = new Document();

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(doc, System.out);
```

Deserialization:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Document doc = u.unmarshal(System.in);
```

Replace `System.out` and `System.in` by your actual streams and you are ready to go.

There is a short tutorial regarding JAXB Annotations in the JAXB tutorial:

- http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_1-A-Survey-Of-JAXB-Annotations.html

Comment: Oh. If there's way to work without xsd precondition - it is great. Thanks.

Comment: +1 - @Dragon, Also since JAXB (JSR-222) implementations are configuration by exception you only need to add annotations where you want the XML representation to differ from the default:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Answer (score 0):

When JAXB is a bit too much of a powerhouse, and a simpler solution could be better, I generally try [Castor](http://castor.codehaus.org/xml-framework.html).

The good part is, you can use the simple introspection mode, quick and easy, and if you ever feel like you need more control over your generated XML, add a descriptor or mapping, but both are optional.